# Hyper-V is there a webinterface to start/shutdown the VMs?

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I´m using a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Hyper-V.

Now I´m searching for a way for a normal user to control the VMs on this server.
Is it possible to use a webinterface to start and shutdown the VMs?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

There's not a "built-in" one, but SCVMM 2008 comes with a [web console (the so called "self-service portal")](http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/microsoft-hyper-v-articles/management/installing-configuring-scvmm-2008-self-service-portal.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "normal user."  Do you just mean "user who is using a different machine as their workstation?"  Or do you mean "user with limited permission?"

You can solve the first problem by installing the Remote Server Administrator Toolkit (search for a link to download it) on the user's machine.

You can solve the second problem by giving that user limited permissions to their VMs with AzMan.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: [Second alpha version of Hyper-V Web Interface](http://www.blinkov.com/blog/New_Features/).

What new:

- Authentication
- Bugfixes (hope I not added new bugs)
- Other internal webserver improvements
- Configuration help page added
- Currently 2 types of authentication are supported: Basic and Windows.

System requirements for host system:

- Hyper-V 3.0
- Hyper-V Server 2012, Windows 2012 Server with Hyper-V role, Windows 8 with Hyper-V role.

[Download Hyper-V Web Interface build 0.1.1.0 as self-extracting file](http://www.blinkov.com/files/HyperVWeb/Setup_HyperVWeb_0.1.1.0.exe)

[Download Hyper-V Web Interface build 0.1.1.0 as zip file](http://www.blinkov.com/files/HyperVWeb/Setup_HyperVWeb_0.1.1.0.zip)